# Using rsync to move (not copy) files between directories?

Tags: rsync

I have been using **rsync** to copy files for some time. My understanding is that **rsync** is faster than **cp** when some of the files to transfer are already in the destination directory, transferring only the incremental difference (i.e. the "deltas").

If this is correct, would there be any advantage to using **rsync** to moving the contents of a folder **A**, to say, a folder **B**, with **B** being empty?

The folder **A** has close to 1TB of data (and millions of files in it). The transfer would be done over a local **network** (**A** and **B** being on **different** filesystems, both **mounted** on a supercomputer, e.g. **A** is [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) and **B** is [lustre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_%28file_system%29)).

Aside from that, what flags should I use to ask **rsync** to move (not copy) files from **A** to **B** (i.e. to delete **A** when the transfer has successfully finished)?

Comment: I don't think `rsync` can replace `mv`.  I would expect `mv` to be faster on most file system types when the source and destination are within the same file system, because `rsync` would have to make a copy no matter what, and `mv` could probably get away with changing a few directory entries.  The closest thing I can find to an `rsync mv` is the `--remove-source-files` command, but that does not remove directories.

Comment: Thanks @jw013! Just to clarify, the files are on **different** filesystems, and the transfer would be done on a **network**. Do you know if that would still make `mv` faster?

Comment: Well, `mv` can't operate across a network - it would have to rely a local mount (e.g. NFS).  If the bottleneck is the network, `rsync` would probably be faster than `mv` because `rsync` can do compression.

Comment: By the way `cp` has `-u` option to copy source file if it is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

Comment: What about this: Create a timestamp, then rsync all the files to remote. When done, delete all local files older than timestamp.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can pass `--remove-source-files` to rsync to move files instead of copying them.

But in your case, there's no point in using rsync, since the destination is empty. A plain `mv` will do the job as fast as possible.

In your case, what could make a difference to performance is the choice of network protocol, if you have a choice among NFS, Samba, sshfs, sftp, rsync over ssh, tar piped into ssh, etc. The relative speed of these methods depends on the file sizes, the network and disk bandwidth, and other factors, so there's no way to give general advice, you'll need to run your own benchmarks.

Comment: Just to reiterate what Caleb says, if you are worried about corruption due to e.g. a flaky network, rsync can make sense, as it verifies every file it writes by checksumming the blocks as it writes them.

Comment: the `--remove-source-files` only deletes the files in the source. if you want to clear our the source, wouldn't you have to do an rm -rf (or `find` all directories and pass `-delete`) on the source after rsync runs successfully?

Comment: @DanielS.Sterling rsync doesn't checksum blocks after writing them (it uses checksums to find which parts of existing files were updated and need to be synchronized).  You can do a second sync with `--checksum` to tell it to verify the results of the first synchronization.

Comment: I am migrating data from one data pool to another. For me this flag makes sense because I want to run the data on the other pool for a week or so (they are new disks) before removing them from the original pool. This flag lets me do that, ensuring everything is in sync just before deleting them from the old pool.

Comment: @Clement not according to the rsync man page discussing the -c flag: -c "Note  that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-file checksum that is generated as the file is transferred"
So Rsync may do a better job than mv to a different volume / host if you are concerned with data loss.

Comment: @openCivilisation, yes, it verifies data in transfer; but it doesn't check that the writes were properly committed to storage (you need an extra pass with --checksum after the fact if you want that).  In which cases would that work better than mv?

Comment: Also, rsync can not use multi-dirs as sender, like `mv A B C D`

Comment: Doesn't `rsync` flush file system buffers whereas `mv` can cause data loss?

Comment: @darw You mean if there's a system crash during a copy+delete move (move between different filesystems), which results in the source file being deleted but the target not being written? That can happen both with mv and with rsync.

Comment: @Qinsi rsync can use multiple source directories just like mv.

Comment: @Clément `--checksum` is useful if there may be files in the destination that have the same timestamp and size but different content. It doesn't verify that the writes are committed to storage: if they're still in cache, it's just reading back from the cache.

Comment: It is also superior to `mv` when it comes to handling of duplicate files/ files that already exist in the destination path.

Answer (score 51):

Since `--remove-source-files` does not remove directories, I issue the following commands to *move* files over ssh:

```
rsync -avzh --remove-source-files --progress /source/ user@server:/target \
&&  find /source -type d -empty -delete
```

I personally like the `--progress` feature, as I do this transfer manually. Remove it if you're using a script. I expect that it slows down transfers marginally.
The `find` command's delete option only deletes empty directories – do not use `rm -rf`, as it may delete non-empty directories in case a file was not transferred. The `-delete` option turns on the `-depth` option so that empty directory trees are deleted from the "bottom" up.

Comment: `-delete` is much nicer than `-exec rmdir {} +` etc

Comment: I would skip the asterisk because and just have trailing slashes / with paths if doing this locally. If you use asterisk rsync will skip hidden files such as .htaccess or .htpasswd (if any)

Comment: You should execute the `find` command only if rsync exists successfully. Otherwise, you'll remove empty directories in the source that you might actually want to preserve. Use the ampersand operator, so: `rsync ... && find ...`

Comment: You probably want to add `-depth` to the find statement.  This causes a depth-first traversal, allowing the leaf directories to be deleted, and then, if the parent directories now become empty, they can be deleted too.  Without this you need to run the find...delete several times.

Comment: **NB:** if your `/source` is actually a symlink, `find` will not delete any empty folders after `rsync` is finished. You have to `cd` into `/source` and then run `find . -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: @dsz when you use `-delete` the `-depth` action is automatically enabled

Comment: @GDP2  You can also just add an extra slash after the symlink name (e.g. `/source/`), then `find` will traverse past the symlink.

Comment: Maybe I am a little bit picky, but can it actually not delete the source directory inside destination like `mv` does? For instance, moving empty `src` dir to `dest` dir would lead to still empty `dest` dir.

Comment: **EDIT** 
U can achieve it by specifing source as `source` not as `source/`, rsync is picky

Answer (score 23):

In general as [Gilles said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43998/1925) there is no advantage to using `rsync` to move files when `mv` will get the same job done simpler and there is no potential speed gain between ordinary file systems.

There are however some times when there is an advantage. In particular, if you have any doubts about the stability of either the source, the destination, or the machine doing the work, using `rsync` gives you resume ability. This can be a notable advantage if you transfer is very large and, say, your power grid is unreliable. Using rsync will be a more stable way to avoid data corruption in the event of a failure and pick up where you left off.

Comment: I'd say this is a huge advantage. In fact, I'd say `mv` is only better if the target and source are in the same partition, so that `mv` only edits the file's metadata instead of doing a copy.

Comment: One time I need `rsync` rather than mv is when I want to preserve the folder structure (if you use `--relative`).

Comment: rsync can though preserve hard links within moved contents, if you ask it to do, while mv cannot.

Answer (score 19):

> would there be any advantage to using rsync to moving the contents of a folder A, to say, a folder B, with B being empty?

I've found myself in a situation where rsync IS faster than mv simply because mv cannot handle the number of files in the directory. I have 1.8 million photos from a security camera that ran for 20 days and the mv command exits with a failure because it cannot allocate resources.

rsync however, seems to handle all the files without a problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to **recursively merge** directories... move one directory into another directory with potentially **duplicate** directory names, then please see my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/566774/whats-the-best-way-to-merge-two-directories-on-the-same-filesystem-in-linux/882821#882821) on serverfault.com. `mv` does a poor job when directories exist with the same name, and `rsync` copies (read + write full data) every file instead of just moving them (read and write only metadata).

Comment: Please add the sources here. I thin it's really good script so it might give your answer the attention it deserves.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Bash script that implements an `rsync`-based `mv`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo -e "Would you like to use a relative path to your source?[y/n?]\n"
read ans
if [[ $ans == y ]]; then
    echo -e "Relative source?\n"
    read source
    source="`pwd`/$source"
elif [[ $ans == n ]]; then
    echo -e "Absolute path to your source?\n"
    read source
    source=${source/"~/"/"/home/jim/"}  
else
    echo -e "Use small cap 'y' or 'n' only."    
    exit 
fi

echo -e "Would you like to use a relative path to your destination?[y/n?]\n"
read ans2
if [[ $ans2 == y ]]; then
    echo -e "Relative destination?\n"
    read dest
    dest="`pwd`/$dest"
    dest=${dest/"~/"/"/home/jim/"}  
elif [[ $ans2 == n ]]; then
    echo -e "Absolute path to your destination?\n"
    read dest   
    dest=${dest/"~/"/"/home/jim/"}
else
    echo -e "Use small cap 'y' or 'n' only."    
    exit 
fi
rsync -avh --remove-source-files --info=progress2 ${source} ${dest} && find ${source} -type d -empty -delete
```

[Rsync's](https://serverfault.com/questions/219013/showing-total-progress-in-rsync-is-it-possible) `--info=progress2` option shows statistics based on the whole transfer, rather than individual files. The script's `find` command only deletes empty directories. [As others did already mention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115352/346682), Rsync's resume ability makes it a more stable way of moving files.

To alias the script as mv add the following lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias mv='~/ComputerScience/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/mvRsync.sh'
alias sudo="sudo "
```

Replace my specific path in the first of the lines above with the one of your choosing. Aliasing sudo [is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209913/how-does-alias-sudo-sudo-work) if you plan on using the alias with sudo.

Disadvantages of this script:

- No `tab` key completion of paths as with the `mv` command. This can be solved by rewriting this script so that it accepts CLI arguments instead of taking user's input with `read`.

Comment: Whoa... your username had me doing a doubletake... kudos to you, good robot usses! But seriously, this kind of contribution deserves recognition, sorry I only have one upvote to give. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

`--remove-source-files` is perfectly fine if source and destination are on different volumes, but if they are on the same, you can use the following method to really **move** files.

Before:

```
find /test
/test
/test/empty_dir
/test/src
/test/src/50GB.bin
```

Execute rsync:

```
# SECONDS=0
# rsync --delete --recursive --backup --backup-dir=/test/dst /test/empty_dir/ /test/src
# echo "rsync needed $SECONDS seconds"
rsync needed 0 seconds
```

After:

```
find /test
/test
/test/dst
/test/dst/50GB.bin
/test/empty_dir
/test/src
```

This works because the `--backup-dir` feature moves and **not** copies files and as we compared `/src` against an empty dir it "deletes" everything to `/dst`. But note: It's still slower than `mv` as rsync executes a move on every file and not only on the root dir as `mv` would.

If you want to delete the (now empty) `/src` dir, use another rsync hack:

```
rsync --recursive --delete --include="/src**" --exclude="*" /test/empty_dir/ "/test"
```

Comment: This looks useful but I'm confused by what the role of `/test/empty_dir/` as the rsync source dir is.

Comment: Because you are sycing the empty dir to the dir, which contains the files, rsync would delete them. But because the `--backup-dir` option is used, it instead moves them to this "backup dir".

Answer (score -1):

I guess this smal script works:

```
copy_from=$(realpath "/tmp/a")
copy_to=$(realpath "/tmp/b")

while read from_file; do from_subdir=$(dirname $from_file | sed "s|$copy_from/||"); to_dir=$copy_to/$from_subdir; echo "Move: [$from_file] to [$to_dir]"; test ! -d $to_dir && mkdir -p $to_dir; mv $from_file $to_dir; done <<< $(find "$copy_from" -type f)
```

Comment: You fail to quote expansions, reading values that may contain backslashes wrongly, trimming whitespace from read values, using `sed` on data that is not text, using `sed` with unsanitized shell variables, needless testing for directory before `mkdir -p`, and reading the output from `find` with newline as the delimiter even though pathnames may contain newlines.  There is also an issue if the source path is a substring of the destination path. You also do not consider the actual questions posed by the asker.